# I can't take data from my HTML form and save it to my database in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm using an HTML template form, from where if someone contacts me through that form I want to save it in my DB.But I could make it to save the data in DB.My codes are below.

MY HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'home' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="name">                                             
<input type="email" name="email">                                               
<input type="text"   name="subject">
<textarea class="form-control" name="message"></textarea>
<a class="contact-btn" href="" role="button">submit</a>                                             
</form>
```

MY VIEW

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        subject = request.POST.get("subject")
        message = request.POST.get("message")

        contact_details = contact()
        contact_details.name = name
        contact_details.email = email
        contact_details.subject = subject
        contact_details.message = message
        contact_details.save()
        return redirect
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

URL

```
path('', contact.views.home, name='home'),
```

MODEL

```
class contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    message = models.TextField()
```

When I enter some data in the form field and press submit button nothing happens. Sometimes the home page reloaded while I press the submit button but nothing is going in my DB.In the admin panel, I saw only my created model object(I create 1 manually) but nothing else is going on to my DB.

Comment: I guess you are missing `"` in action paramter, it sould be: `action="{% url 'home' %}"`

Comment: You don't seem to have said what the problem is. What happens? What error do you get?

Comment: Apart from anything else, you should be using a Django form. In this case, a ModelForm.

Comment: @Reema Parakh I accidentally miss that here while posting but in my code that okay but still not working

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman when i enter some data in the form and press submit button nothing happens..sometimes it reload the home page but nothing goes in the DB

Comment: how do you expect to submit your form if you don't have a submit button? Your button is a `<a>` tag linking to the same page. Read up on how to create an HTML form and a submit button.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I'm not using django form rather I'm using raw HTML form.

Comment: I know, I can see that. But you *should* be using a Django form.

Comment: That's still just a link to the home page, not a submit button.

Comment: @ dirkgroten I add type="submit" but still not working.

Comment: unless you use javascript to catch the onclick event of your <a> tag, it will default to fetch whatever you have as "href" attribute. It won't submit the form. Look in your browser developer tools, Network tab, what your browser is actually doing, you'll see a GET request for the same page, not a POST request.

Comment: @dirkgroten yes, you are right. It only see the get but not the post. What should i do to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dirk says, you don't have a submit button. You just have a link styled to look like a button. But just because it looks like one, doesn't mean it will act as one.

```
<button class="contact-btn" type="submit">submit</button>
```

Comment: that's not possible, if your <button> is inside the <form> it has to work.

Comment: my button is inside the form. Do the href tag has anything to do with the POST method?

Comment: What href? A button does not have one.

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you very much.It worked. I miss the closing tag.sorry about that

Comment: @dirkgroten after clicking the submit button 1/2 times doesn't do anything I mean it should redirect me to the home page as I set the action to home.html. Hitting the submit button 3 or 4 times and then it reloads the page. What's gone wrong here?

Comment: what do you mean "I set the action to home.html"? use your developer tools to check what's happening in your browser (the network tab), that'll pinpoint where the problem is.